# C++ Struct,Reference and Instancing the right way?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I'm creating a replay system Basically it stores user inputs as:

```
std::list<ReplayBuffer>
```

which is a:

```
struct ReplayBuffer
{
    std::bitset<10> flags;
    float frameTime;
    uint64_t frameID;

};
```

now I've created two more structs, ReplayFile (the file information), and ReplayFileWriter(Write the file information into a file of course)

```
struct ReplayFile
{
    ReplayFile(std::list<ReplayBuffer>* _buffers) {
        time_t t = time(0);
        date = ctime(&t);
        _version = 1;
        buffers = *_buffers;
    }
    uint16_t _version;
    char* date;
    std::list<ReplayBuffer> buffers;
};

struct ReplayFileWriter
{
   std::ofstream file;
   
   ReplayFileWriter(ReplayFile *data) {
       file.open("replay.cdr", std::ofstream::out);
       file << data;
       file.close();

   }


};
```

What I want to do is, type this:

```
ReplayFileWriter(new ReplayFile(&buffers));
```

so I pass to ReplayFile the adress of the buffers (list) and to ReplayFileWriter the adress a instance of ReplayFile) how I'm supposed to do this (I'm new to cpp, watched some videos into pointer, but when using as parameters is hard to find the right way to place "* and &"

Comment: What happens when you type the shown line? Please show the error messages you get. Seems to compile [fine](https://godbolt.org/z/EaTar9).

Comment: Think about the pointer you create with `new ReplayFile(...)`, when is it passed to `delete`? There's no need for pointers there, pass by value instead and rely on the standard move-semantics to avoid extra copying.

Comment: Be aware that `ctime` returns a pointer to a static buffer, overwritten every time `ctime` or `asctime` is called.

Comment: `file << data` writes the address stored in `data` to the file. The file now contains 8 or 16 hex digits. Probably not what you had in mind.

Comment: Unclear why `ReplayFileWriter` is even a class. It could be implemented as a plain function. In fact, that plain function should probably be named `ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const ReplayFile& rf);`

Comment: @cigien yeah it compiles but the outgoing file is like this: it is supposed to have more data https://imgur.com/a/1xURnqp

Comment: Ok, then your question should be edited to describe this problem exactly.

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably looking for is something like this:

```
struct ReplayBuffer { /* as in your code */ };

struct ReplayFile {
    explicit ReplayFile(const std::list<ReplayBuffer>& _buffers)
        : _version(1), buffers(_buffers) {
      time_t t = time(nullptr);
      date = ctime(&t);
    }
    uint16_t _version;
    std::string date;
    std::list<ReplayBuffer> buffers;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const ReplayFile& data) {
  /* Write contents of `data` to `os` here.
     Implementation left as an exercise for the reader. */
  return os;
}

void WriteReplayFile(const ReplayFile& data) {
   file.open("replay.cdr", std::ofstream::out);
   file << data;
   file.close();
}

int main() {
  std::list<ReplayBuffer> buffers = ...;  // initialized somehow.
  WriteReplayFile(ReplayFile(buffers));
}
```

The interesting part is in `operator<<`. That's where you get to define your file format.

Comment: wow this is a better one, so I dont need to duplicate memory usage by instancing a new Replay buffer, thanks